# Depth first search using adjacency list

Tags: c, graph, depth-first-search, adjacency-list

I m trying to unterstand the code below but there´s something not clear in DFS function

enter code here

```
#include<stdio.h>  

typedef struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    int vertex;
}node;

node *G[20];  

int visited[20];
int n;
void read_graph();
void insert(int,int); 
void DFS(int);

void main()
{
    int i;
    read_graph();
    //initialised visited to 0

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        visited[i]=0;

    DFS(0);
}

void DFS(int i)
{
    node *p;

    printf("\n%d",i);
    p=G[i];
    visited[i]=1;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        i=p->vertex;
        if(!visited[i])
            DFS(i);
        p=p->next;
    }
}

void read_graph()
{
    int i,vi,vj,no_of_edges;
    printf("Enter number of vertices:");

    scanf("%d",&n);

    //initialise G[] with a null

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        G[i]=NULL;
        //read edges and insert them in G[]

        printf("Enter number of edges:");
        scanf("%d",&no_of_edges);

        for(i=0;i<no_of_edges;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter an edge(u,v):");
            scanf("%d%d",&vi,&vj);
            insert(vi,vj);
        }
    }
}

void insert(int vi,int vj)
{
    node *p,*q;

    //acquire memory for the new node
    q=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    q->vertex=vj;
    q->next=NULL;

    //insert the node in the linked list number vi
    if(G[vi]==NULL)
        G[vi]=q;
    else
    {
        //go to end of the linked list
        p=G[vi];

        while(p->next!=NULL)
            p=p->next;
        p->next=q;
    }
}
```

how does  the backtracking happen after terminating the while loop in the function DFS() ? i don´t get it

Thx

Comment: Step one in understanding an algorithm is to format the code in such a way that it is _readable_ as to what is done. The code you posted looked horrible.

Comment: There is no "back tracking". Your original article doesn't mention that either. There is only a return from recursion when `DFS(i)` finds that `G[i]` has no more vertices to traverse.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a DFS (Depth First *Search*), as nothing is searched for. All that your DFS function does is traverse all edges, marking their nodes as visited. Once done, you only know if this is a *connected* graph - if there are any edges that have not been visited, then they have not been marked, and so cannot be reached from `G[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

the original code is not mine .. i just found it on this website : http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2014/03/depth-first-search-dfs-traversal-of-a-graph.html